# Disrespectful answer from a user

Tags: discussion

I've asked a question, good or bad, but very concise and objective. This is one of the [answers I got](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/622061/390930). Where the user is attacking me instead of answering a question.

Not only in the question but also in a comment.

I don't think that's a fair treat, and ask this answer be removed or at least modified.

Comment: Can you explain why you feel the user is attacking you? I don't see what part of the answer you are perceiving as an attack. You are absolutely right about the comment, that was indeed rude and uncalled for, but it has been deleted. Without that comment, I don't see the answer itself as an attack. It's an unhelpful answer, yes, but why is it an attack?

Comment: @terdon probably i read the answer after read the comment. So the word "You" already sounds bad. Thanks for listening and removing the comment. Feel better now.

Comment: Yes, I can completely understand why you would read the answer as more aggressive if you'd first read the comment (I didn't delete it, by the way, another mod got it).

Comment: Sadly, that's (mostly) the entire Stack Exchange network in a nutshell.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We expect all contributors at U&L to abide by the [Code of Conduct](https://unix.stackexchange.com/conduct). If you see a post or a comment that you believe falls outside those guidelines, then please flag it. Doing so will bring it to the attention of the site's moderation team, who can then deal with it.